# How to delete your main world on a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I'm on a server with multiple artificially created worlds. For example I created a void world for a spawnhub. But now I want to delete the default worlds. Nether, End and World. I can't delete those right now because they keep regenerating after a restart. I want to change the default world to the one with the void. People should also spawn there on initial join. Does anyone have any idea how to do this. I'm using MultiVerse.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't necessarily have to delete the default worlds.**

To change the world in which new players spawn by default, modify the value of the `level-name` property in `server.properties` to your desired world name.

If you still want to delete the originally generated world, you can do so with `/mv delete` which completely removes the world folders from your server or `/mv remove` which *unloads* the world but keeps the world folder after you have changed the server properties. Keep in mind that it is often dangerous to directly delete files and folders.

Comment: those mv commands don't work as it says the command isn't executed. It works for created worlds. But not for the default ones.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "it says the command isn't executed"? Is that a message shown in chat or console? Did you execute `/mv delete` or `/mv remove` after you made sure `server.properties` did not contain the name of the world which you want to delete? Were you in the world when you sent the commands? Can you paste the command which you have executed?

Comment: Is this the in-game command line? Just does not seem to have a `mv` command

Comment: `mv` is a command from the Multiverse plugin.